# Fazer objeto se mexer na tela

Tags: javascript

Resolvi criar um pequeno joguinho daqueles de destruir blocos com uma bola.

Só consegui fazer a plataforma andar para a direita e esquerda usando o teclado, porém não consigo fazer a bola andar.

```js
  //código de teclas: 37=Esquerda - 38=Cima - 39=Direita - 40=Baixo


  //variavel charX = posição da plataforma na tela
  //bolaX e bolaY posição da bola na tela
  var charX = 0;
  var bolaX = 0;
  var bolaY = 0;

  //função move = relativo ao movimento da plataforma
  function move(){
      //variavel obj, que recebe char
      let obj=document.getElementById("char");
      //variavel tecla, 
      var tecla=event.keyCode;

      //se a tecla precionada for a seta pra esquerda
      if(tecla==37){
          //o charX recebe -10
          charX-=15;
          //charX, com o novo valor, muda a posição do objeto
          obj.style.left=charX+"px";
      }
      //o mesmo do de cima
      else if(tecla==39){
          charX+=15;
          obj.style.left=charX+"px";
      }

  }
  //function bola = relativo ao movimento da bola
  function bola(){

      //var lado=numero aleatorio de 1 a 8, que definirão para onde a bola andará
      var lado=Math.floor(Math.random()*8); //1-norte 2-nordeste 3-leste 4-sudeste 5-sul 6-sudoeste 7-oeste 8-noroeste
      let obj=document.getElementById("bola");

      //switch lado pra movimentar a bola.
      switch(lado){
          case 1:
              bolaY-=10;
              bolaX+=0;
              obj.style.top=bolaY+"px";
              obj.style.left=bolaX+"px";
              break;
          case 2:
              bolaY-=5;
              bolaX+=5;
              obj.style.top=bolaY+"px";
              obj.style.left=bolaX+"px";
              break;
          case 3:
              bolaY+=0;
              bolaX+=10;
              obj.style.top=bolaY+"px";
              obj.style.left=bolaX+"px";
              break;
          case 4:
              bolaY+=5;
              bolaX-=5;
              obj.style.top=bolaY+"px";
              obj.style.left=bolaX+"px";
              break;
          case 5:
              bolaY+=10;
              bolaX+=0;
              obj.style.top=bolaY+"px";
              obj.style.left=bolaX+"px";
              break;
          case 6:
              bolaY+=5;
              bolaX-=5;
              obj.style.top=bolaY+"px";
              obj.style.left=bolaX+"px";
              break;
          case 7:
              bolaY+=0;
              bolaX-=10;
              obj.style.top=bolaY+"px";
              obj.style.left=bolaX+"px";
              break;
          case 8:
              bolaY+=5;
              bolaX-=5;
              obj.style.top=bolaY+"px";
              obj.style.left=bolaX+"px";
              break;

                }
          }


  document.addEventListener("keydown",move);
  window.addEventListener("load",bola);
```

```css
#bola{
    left: 200px;
    top: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
```

```html
<div id="quadro">
    <div id="char"></div>
    <div id="bola"></div>
</div>
```

Já tentei usar um `while` dentro do `switch` que faria o comando se repetir até a posição da bola atingir um limite, mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Uma dica. Use o [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) para fazer a animação, ao invés do loop.
O requestAnimationFrame já controla o FPS automático pra você.

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao site. Poderia acrescentar um exemplo de como usar, pra deixar a resposta mais completa? Obrigado.